# Error while adding cordova platform ios

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

I update my Cordova version 3.6.0 to 4.0.0, Which is latest one on today's date. It allow to add me android platform but while going to add iOS platform it gives following error.

```
Unable to fetch platform ios: Error: No compatible version found: cordova-ios@'>=8458588.0.0-0 <8458589.0.0-0'
Valid install targets:
["3.5.0","3.6.0","3.6.1","3.6.3"]
```

I have Xcode6 install on my system. But I can't figure out the problem.

Answer (score 14):

I solved this problem by reinstalling Cordova using this command

```
$ sudo npm install -g cordova
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this below command in your terminal project path
rm -rf ~/.cordova

Answer (score 2):

It's correct.

Cordova 4.0 is for cordova cli version, that is not the same project as Cordova . Cordova cli uses last available version con each platform (3.6.4 for Android) .

http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/10/16/cordova-4.html

Answer (score 0):

I had close to this issue, except my error message was:

```
Failed to fetch platform ios
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
```

After a couple tries, it worked. The command `cordova platform add ios` does fail to complete if I'm not connected to the internet, so I do suspect that the external web service that it relies on had a brief downtime.

Comment: I'm having this same problem, if you fixed, tell me know

Comment: @PedroHenrique As described, my fix was to wait some time for the suspected Cordova web service down time to be resolved.