# Cordova cli 4.0 can't install ios platform update

Tags: cordova, cordova-3, cordova-4

I have updated cordova via npm install -g cordova because I was getting warning about unsafe older cordova versions in the google play store console.

I'm trying to update my project like so:

```
cordova platform update ios
```

but this gives me the following error:

> npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-ios npm http 200
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-ios Error: No compatible version
>   found: cordova-ios@'>=8458588.0.0-0 <8458589.0.0-0' Valid install
>   targets: ["3.5.0","3.6.0","3.6.1","3.6.3"]

should I downgrade to cordova CLI 3.6? If so, how can I do this best?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646052/error-while-adding-cordova-platform-ios